# Can set design height if height is already set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

c# can set design height if height is set

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="SQL_Reports.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SQL_Reports"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Width="669"
    Title="Daily SQL Reports" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
    MinHeight="530" 
    TitleAlignment="Center" 
    MinWidth="677" 
    d:DesignHeight="927" >
```

I am trying to set the design height so i can view my content in Visual Studio
but i also want the height of the WPF to be 530 but when I set the height the designer stays to 530 and not what I set the Design Height to be.

Comment: The issue which you're mentioning is happening only when `Height` is set. If your're setting `MinHeight` instead, it's works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the MinHeight="530" when you are designing.
And add it again when youre done.

I don't believe you can define a runtime height and a design height at the same time. 
Maybe you can try the d:LayoutOverrides attribute.